# Querying for null using Casbah

Tags: null, casbah

I'm using Casbah to connect to and query a Mongo database. Right now I'm trying to query on fields where the value is not null.

Using straight Mongo syntax, the query I'm wanting would be `collection.find({"key" : {$ne : null }} )`

In casbah, I've tried `collection.find("key" $ne null)`, which doesn't compile and `collection.find("key" $ne MongoDBObject(null))` which throws a null pointer exception at runtime, as well as `collection.find("key" $ne org.bson.BSON.NULL)` which just doesn't actually query properly.

`collection.find("key" -> null)` will work to query the ones that are null.

My syntax might have been subtly off in the above examples, but the essential idea should be conveyed.

Any ideas anybody?

I cannot change the database so that the null entries just don't exist. That's out of my control. I can change to not casbah, but I'd really rather not.

Answer (score 1):

You can often use None for null in scala. Here you want:

```
collection.find("key" $ne None)
```

Comment: This is not working: "error: None.type is not a valid query parameter."

Comment: @PhilippSander bummer it worked at one point I am pretty sure. I have since burned all MongoDB instances from all servers I work on, and burned all MongoDB knowledge from my brain to use better datastores. Good luck though!

Answer (score 1):

```
collection.find(MongoDBObject("key" -> MongoDBObject("$ne" -> None)))
```

This does the job. I have been stuck on this too